# Why is Algorithm 8 of Neal (2000) a valid sampler?

Tags: bayesian, monte-carlo, markov-process, convergence, dirichlet-process

[image]I have been having difficulty understanding why Algorithm 8 of [Neal (2000)](https://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/fall11/cos597C/reading/Neal2000a.pdf) is a valid sampler.

I am looking for lecture notes that include a nice explanation of the proof. Does anyone know of any such reference?

Comment: Please provide the background so that a reader does not need reading Neal (200) first.

Comment: Thank you for the edit, I will be sure to do this in the future.

Comment: @Xi'an It's a good reading though :D

Answer (score 2):

For brevity, I'm omitting the normalizing constants.  Under the standard (Polya urn) Gibbs Sampler for a vanilla DP, the model would be:

$$
P(c_i = c\mid \ldots) \propto \begin{cases}
n_{\neg i, c}f(Y_i\mid\theta_c) &\text{ for }1 \leq c \leq k^{\neg i}\\
\alpha\int_{\theta} f(y_i\mid\theta)dG_0(\theta) &\text{ for }c = k^{\neg i} + 1
\end{cases}
$$

Doing that integral analytically is difficult, if $G_0$ is not conjugate to $F$.
Some of Neal's algorithms offer various perturbations of this model trying to bypass the need for conjugacy, by doing that integral implicitly.  By sampling $\theta$ from $G_0$, then weighting by $f(y_i\mid\theta)$, you effectively get samples from $f(y_i\mid\theta)dG_0(\theta)$.  In fact, I think algorithm 7 does just this (with a single sample per iteration).  Algorithm 8 recognizes that a single sample doesn't represent that integral very well, so we generate $m$ samples from $G_0$, and weight them accordingly.